# Patent specification page layout

Tags: specification

I am going to write an application and send it to WIPO, because I want patent coverage in different countries, including United States.

I would like to discover what page layout my patent specification should have. As I see there are two main types of layouts:

1. One column (very close to LaTeX `uspatent` style layout) like this one: http://www.lens.org/images/patent/US/6067383/A/US_6067383_A.pdf
   [image: one column layout]
2. Two column layout, like this one: http://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/1998047290/A1/WO_1998_047290_A1.pdf
   [image: two column layout]

What layout should I prefer and where I may found detailed page layout and typography requirements for patent specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the second format. That is the way the U.S. patent office formats it when they print it, not the way any patent office wants to get it from you.  WIPO's format requirements are in the PCT Applicant's Guide. I am having trouble pasting in the URL but it comes up on a google search. It is written in a very bureaucratic manner.